# Block web-page containing a specific word in Safari

Tags: macos, safari

I would like to know if there is any Mac Safari plugin to block any web page containing a specific word in its url or in its content.

For example, suppose we take the word 'abc', the following link must be blocked : wwww.dfrrraabc.com

A web page containing 'abc' in its content must also be blocked.

I don't know if a plugin like this already exists for Safari.

Comment: Yes, but… Note of caution: this seems like a bad idea. generally, you shouldn’t block domains based on strings within that domain. blocking `abc***`, `***abc`, or `*abc*` will block all sites containing the string `abc`. `abc`  needs to be really bad for you to do so. We’re only talking about domain names here - not IPs.

Comment: To save others some time: I don't think [Adblock](https://adblockplus.org/) can block pages based on content, even with [custom filter rules](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters) (as [suggested elsewhere](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/safari-keyword-filtering.1303569/#post-14113549)).

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source extension for Safari named [PeyvandhaBlocker](https://github.com/pooriaazimi/PeyvandhaBlocker.safariextension) to prevent loading an automatic page redirection based on IP (in the URL) and element type. You can get it and modify `allowContentToLoad` function in `global.html` file to take decisions based on URL or context of loaded web pages, and then edit the `content.js` for the block action you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an App Store app called **Search Guardian**.

- Download the app.
- Enable it by going to Settings -> Safari -> Extensions and move the slider to 'enabled'.
- Also go to Settings -> Safari -> Content Blockers and move the slider to 'enabled'.